# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP) Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm new to Xcode and idk why i have this error, can someone help me with this? much appreciated. This is basically for users to enter their verification code given and it will display a message based on the particular code.

VerificationController

```
import UIKit

class VerificationController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var verification: UITextField!
    @IBAction func enter(_ sender: Any) {

            if verification.text != ""
            {
                if verification.text == "123"
                {
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)

                }
                else if verification.text == "234"
                {
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
                }
            }
        }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

SecondController

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    var myString1 = "Hello 123"
    var myString2 = "Hello 234"



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if (VerificationController().verification.text! == "123")
            {   
                 label.text = myString1
            }
        else if (VerificationController().verification.text! == "234")
            {
                 label.text = myString2
            }


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }  
}
```

[[IMAGE OF ERROR]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkc5C.png)

Comment: You're creating new object of "VerificationController()" and giving guaranty that  verification.text never be nil and checking if it equals to "123" or not. are you assigning value for verification.text at the timer of creating object of "VerificationController()" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the verification text to the `SecondViewController` in **prepare(forSegue)** method and access the same:

In  `VerificationController`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {
        let secondVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        secondVC.verificationText =  verification.text
    }
}
```

Then in `SecondViewController`:

```
 var verificationText:String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    if (verificationText == "123")
    {
        label.text = myString1
    }
    else if (verificationText == "234")
    {
        label.text = myString1
    }

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I really wish i can but i don't have enough rep points :( if not i would've upvote  100x

Comment: @Kinja Np, Thanks.

Comment: @Kinja Instead of changing your question's title to include "SOLVED", if this answer solves your issue you should accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark to its left.

Comment: @maddy ohh okok, thanks, sorry I didn't know much about stack overflow